# Tkinter GUI Assistance

Tags: python, tkinter, project

I asked a few weeks ago for some help but got told I was too vague in my question or request. 
I am currently making a rebuild of zork for my A Level project, I have completed the actual story line but have not made a GUI, nor have I ever made a GUI. 
I thought to leave this till last and get the actual program working.

**I am needing to make this GUI or my project will not get a grade, please read below [NOTE: I AM USING TKINTER]:
All I need to do is have an input box which allows the user to input a command in the game.
A text box which displays the game's text so they can see what the storyline is.**

I do not know how to do this fully. This is just a sample of the code so you can understand the actual project. 
Any help would be appriciated!

```
#from tkinter import *
#root = Tk()
#root.title("Zork Project")
#root.geometry("500x500")
#root.mainloop()

import os
loop = 3
while loop == 3:
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("------------------Welcome To Alex's Zork Project - Python Edition------------------")
    print("-----------------------------------Version 0.0.2-----------------------------------")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("---You are standing in an open plain, to the north is an abandoned looking house---")
    print("----To the south is a forest, next to you is a broken lockbox screwed to a post----")
    print("---------------------------There is a door to the east-----------------------------")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#First scenario & first input.
    first = input("What do you plan to do? ")
    if first.lower() == ("open lockbox"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Upon opening the lockbox it reveals a file stating on the front:")
        print("'INGSOC; Ministry of Peace'")
        print("Upon opening the file you see 'Mission Objective: Reclaim Lost Records.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("take lockbox"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("This is not possible, it is screwed on too tightly.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("n"):
            print("You step closer to the house, not much going on there.")
            print("You go back to the lockbox...")
            loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("north"):
            print("You step closer to the house, not much going on there.")
            print("You go back to the lockbox...")
            loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("go north"):
            print("You step closer to the house, not much going on there.")
            print("You go back to the lockbox...")
            loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("east"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("e"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.")
    elif first.lower() == ("go east"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("open door"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("It is not possible to open the door.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("remove boards"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("The boards are fastened securely, we cannot physically remove them!")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("look at house"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("The house is desolate and abandoned, it may have been used by the resistance as an outpost many moons ago.")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("read file"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("The file says: 'INGSOC; MoP mission to obtain lost mission files from the 'Resistance.'")
        print("The file name is labelled 'Op Banner II - MoP reclimation of mission files.'")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("jump"):
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("How High?")
        loop = 4
    elif first.lower() == ("south"):
        loop = 8
    elif first.lower() == ("go south"):
        loop = 8
    elif first.lower() == ("s"):
        loop = 8
    else:
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Command Unknown. For control help please type 'help'.")
        loop = 4
```

Comment: Tkinter GUI is simple to learn. You really should check out the youtube tutorials on GUI.

Comment: This is still too broad. You need to work through a tkinter tutorial, try to solve the problem yourself, then come back here when you have a specific question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have been trying since I last posted... All I have is a square box with the title "zork" nothing else and I have watched like 6 hours of tutorials with no luck.

Comment: Just create a super-simple UI with a large text field (output) on top and an entry (input) on the bottom and read/write from/to those instead of using `input` and `print`. Also, the `while` should probably be replaced with a call to `after` or similar.

Comment: We can only comment on code that you provide, and you haven't provided any code at all that uses tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley forgot to as it was commented out so I could focus on storyline. My bad.

Comment: That tkinter code is useless. You need to try a little harder. As it is, you're asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks for the help! Just ran the code and it comes up as the starting text but if I input a command and press enter it just goes to the next line and nothing happens. Not too sure if this was meant to happen as it seems to come up as 1 text box

Comment: @TheMicks: You may not be typing in the command line at the bottom. There is a text box and a entry field box. The entry field box is at the bottom of the program. I added a new line to add color to the command line. Try the code now.

Comment: @Mike-SMT You sir, are a legend! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is a very easy to use GUI library. Judging by your comment under your question you have tried but failed to understand the basics of Tkinter. You may want to know that if you create your mainloop and then write code after the mainloop it will not be used in your GUI. The mainloop needs to go at the end of your program.

Instead of using `input` and `print` we are going to use `get()` and `insert`.

`get()` is used to retrieve the value of the entry field as a string.

`insert()` is used to write the value directly to the text box at the given index.

The below is a simple tkinter GUI using your existing code. I removed the many print lines as you can get the same results with a triple quote `"""` as triple quotes are multi line quotes. This is not the cleanest way to do things but it should work fine here.

I have added a `\n` at the end of all the strings used in your program to keep the text box looking a bit cleaner as it will move everything to a new line.
I was not sure if you wanted to keep all the text each time the user submits a command or if you wanted to clean the board every time so I went with keeping the text.

We do not need a `while` loop here as everything can be managed with functions.
We do not need to `import os` here.

We can save some lines of code by creating a function to update the text box for us instead of using the commands on each if/else statement.

The below GUI is simple as it only contains a text box and a entry field.
I have bound the Enter/Return button to the entry field so you can submit your commands after you type them. The below code should serve to provide all you need for a simple GUI that will do what you need. Keep in mind There is likely a better way to provide your responses. Probably with a dictionary with your commands being the keys and the responses to the text box being the key value but you can figure that one out.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 0)
#I do not know if you have plans for this loop variable so I left it in the code.
loop = 3

# we need to put the geometry manager grid() after the creation of the widget.
# this will allow us to work with the widget later in the program.
Main_Textbox = tk.Text(root, width = 83, height = 20)
Main_Textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

Command_Line = tk.Entry(root)
Command_Line.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
Command_Line.config(background = "black", foreground = "white")

def start_game():
    Starting_Text = """
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------Welcome To Alex's Zork Project - Python Edition------------------
-----------------------------------Version 0.0.2-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---You are standing in an open plain, to the north is an abandoned looking house---
----To the south is a forest, next to you is a broken lockbox screwed to a post----
---------------------------There is a door to the east-----------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
    # the delete() method is used to clear the text box.
    Main_Textbox.delete(1.0, "end")
    Main_Textbox.insert("end", Starting_Text)

def update_textbox(x):
    Main_Textbox.insert("end", x)
    # the see() method is used to move the view of the text box down with the new text.
    Main_Textbox.see("end")
    Command_Line.delete(0, "end")

def process_commands(Event=None):
    if Command_Line.get().lower() == ("open lockbox"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Upon opening the lockbox it reveals a file stating on the front:
'INGSOC; Ministry of Peace'
Upon opening the file you see 'Mission Objective: Reclaim Lost Records.\n""")
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("take lockbox"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is not possible, it is screwed on too tightly.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("n"):
        update_textbox("""You step closer to the house, not much going on there.
You go back to the lockbox...\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("north"):
        update_textbox("""You step closer to the house, not much going on there.
You go back to the lockbox...\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("go north"):
        update_textbox("""You step closer to the house, not much going on there.
You go back to the lockbox...\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("east"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("e"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("go east"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is a door that is boarded up, it is not possible to remove them.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("open door"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
It is not possible to open the door.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("remove boards"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The boards are fastened securely, we cannot physically remove them!\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("look at house"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The house is desolate and abandoned, it may have been used by the resistance as an outpost many moons ago.\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("read file"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The file says: 'INGSOC; MoP mission to obtain lost mission files from the 'Resistance.'
The file name is labelled 'Op Banner II - MoP reclimation of mission files.'""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("jump"):
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
How High?\n""")
        loop = 4
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("south"):
        loop = 8
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("go south"):
        loop = 8
    elif Command_Line.get().lower() == ("s"):
        loop = 8
    else:
        update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command Unknown. For control help please type 'help'.\n""")
        loop = 4
# this bind() method will allow us to submit our command for processing.
Command_Line.bind("<Return>", process_commands)
start_game()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So if I was to add another scenario such as my loop 8 I would do:
    while loop == 8:
            loop == 8
            update_textbox("""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        You are in a clearing within the forest surround you.

???

Comment: I dont think you need the loop anything. Everything can be done with a basic function.

Comment: Ah right, do you have a contact as I would like to talk through this with you so I can understand how to expand on what you have given me

Comment: like I am trying to add in so when the player goes south it runs the next scenario of the game, but eachtime I try to add it in it seems to fail and not do anything

Comment: You can likely add a command at the end of the if/else statement that is part of south and tell it to move to the next function. That said you will need to ask a new question on the matter so someone can answer if you cant figure it out.